# Calling NS_DispatchToMainThread from WinAPI thread

Tags: winapi, xpcom

I know that most XPCOM methods are not thread safe, but is it safe to send events from WinAPI worker thread to XPCOM main thread using `NS_DispatchToMainThread`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NS_DispatchToMainThread` is safe to be used from any thread.